# Custom two column text

Tags: two-column, minipage, double-sided

I have a problem that can be seen in the below picture. Basically, I want to have one line on the left side of the page, and a description on the right side.

The way I have tried to do this, is by using the minipage environment and  `\qquad` for the horizontal spacing.

[image: What I have so far.]

The problem is now, as you can see in the picture, that the text on the right hand do not line up. I know this is because the `\qquad` command, indents by a fixed mount, and if the text on the left hand is not as long as the previous, I am screwed.

```
\textit{Elastic modulus, \textbf{E}}
\qquad
\begin{minipage}[t]{9cm}
  Steel is easy to bend \textit{elastically} means that it springs back when released. Its resistance to bending, \textit{elastic stiffness}, is set by shape and the property, \textit{elastic modulus, E}. Materials with high \textit{E}, like steel, are intrinsically stiff; those with low \textit{E}, like polyethylene, are not.
\end{minipage}
\textit{Yield strength, \textbf{$\sigma_y$}}
\qquad
\begin{minipage}[t]{9cm}
    This is the 
\end{minipage}
```

I was hoping someone could help me, please!

Regards,
Michael

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a list

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}[font=\normalfont\itshape,leftmargin=4cm,labelwidth=!]
\item[Elastic modulus, \textbf{E}]
  Steel is easy to bend \textit{elastically} means that it springs back when released. Its resistance to bending, \textit{elastic stiffness}, is set by shape and the property, \textit{elastic modulus, E}. Materials with high \textit{E}, like steel, are intrinsically stiff; those with low \textit{E}, like polyethylene, are not.

\item[Yield strength, \textbf{$\sigma_y$}]
    This is the
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ohh wow, why didn't I think of this! Such a simple solution to something I have used way to much time pondering upon! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

another variation on a list.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength\mylistindent
\newcommand{\mylist}[1]{\par\addvspace{2pt}
  \noindent \hangindent\mylistindent
  \makebox[\mylistindent]{#1\hfill}\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\settowidth\mylistindent{the longest entry\qquad}

\mylist{\textit{Elastic modulus, \textbf{E}}} Steel is easy to bend
 \textit{elastically} means that it springs back when released. Its
 resistance to bending, \textit{elastic stiffness}, is set by shape and
 the property, \textit{elastic modulus, E}. Materials with high
 \textit{E}, like steel, are intrinsically stiff; those with low
 \textit{E}, like polyethylene, are not.

\mylist{Second} this is the text for the second item.  It is
  very long, and may require several lines.
\mylist{Another} one more here
\mylist{Final} one more to finish off.

\medskip
\noindent
You'll need to put in some explicit space at the end.

\end{document}
```

[image: indented list, from example code]

it's relatively easy to extend this to allow multiple lines on the left,
in case the element being described is a very long phrase (which would
make the right-hand block ridiculously narrow).  if that feature is needed,
say so, and i will provide the extension.